# Ionic 2 Load items from Promise in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, promise, ionic2

I have home.ts which is calling service.ts to load items from Storage.

```
export class HomePage {

  products;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.products = this.productService.products;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.productService.fetchProducts();                                    
      this.products = this.productService.products;
  }
}

export class ProductService{ 

  products;

  fetchProducts(){    
    this.storage.get('products') // returns a promise which returns data or error    
      .then(
        (products) => {
        // assign to this.expenses only if not null. When first //strt, can be null. If null, assign empty array []
          products? this.products = products : this.products = [];                                            
          console.log("fetch Products:" + this.products);
          return this.products;
      })  
      .catch(
        err => console.log(err)
      );          
  }
```

I then render the items in `home.html`.
The problem is, the items don't get displayed the first time round when the app starts. But if I navigate to another screen and return back to home.ts, the items get rendered back fine. I understand that this is because of ionViewDidEnter and perhaps the first time round, the promise in fetchProducts is asynchronous. But how do I get the items to list the first time round on `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for that. But what would be the specific code in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to handle your async issue is doing the operation inside the callback:

```
ngOnInit(){
      this.productService.fetchProducts()
        .then((res)=>{
          this.products = this.productService.products;
        });                              
}
```

You should also add a `return` statement here:

```
fetchProducts(){    
    return this.storage.get('products') // returns a promise which returns data or error    
      .then(..
```

Here's a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ONOg4FChJpCG81gM7Vlt?p=preview

Comment: It would work for rendering home.ts, but products in productService would be undefined...

Comment: @Jason I've updated my answer but it shouldn't be undefined in the service also..

Comment: omg! It worked! And most importantly, I understand more about Promises and about asynchronous programming

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you could do it in two different ways...

First modify the method so typescript understands that it returns a promise with a list of products:

```
fetchProducts(): Promise<Array<any>> {
  // ...
}
```

---

1) Preloading the information once: so you'll call the `fetchProducts` method only once (probably at startup) in order to load the products *in memory*, and then you'll use the `products` property to get the data

```
// In your app.component.ts
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

    public rootPage: any; // Don't assign the page here yet

    constructor(private platform: Platform,
                private productService: ProductService) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // ...

            this.productService.fetchProducts().then(() => {
                this.rootPage = HomePage;
            });
        });
    }
```

And then in the HomePage, since the data is already on memory, you can just use the `products` property from the service:

```
export class HomePage {

  products;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.products = this.productService.products;
  }

}
```

---

2) Getting the products from the storage every time the user enters to the HomePage:

```
    export class HomePage {

      products;

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.productService.fetchProducts().then((products) => {
          this.products = this.productService.products;
        });   
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you too seba!